# Handle Authentication in NextJS

Tags: authentication, redux, next.js, jwt

I am setting up a new web application and I wanted some advices for handling my authentication workflow.

I am fetching the user's data from a custom backend. Once the user is logged in, I got the access token and the refresh token as well.

I choose NextJs for my front-end with all the benefits it gives. My question is :

Should I handle the Authentication workflow with NextAuth or Redux ?
In the first case with NextAuth, I have never implemented the session hook.
In the redux case, I just dispatch actions and handle the authentication data in the global state of the application.

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I have been used the Next-Auth, It has many problems!
Then I created a new custom API for Google-auth with a token and a CSRF token for every ssr page that update every page loading.

If you want, I can upload it on git for free :)

Comment: Can you details what was your issues ?
Well all I need is to authenticate the user stored in my database. But with some best practices :)

Comment: In many cases, after login from Google-auth, I saw all cookies was deleted. This is cuse to get undefined user because we not have any session! And adding JWT secret key is a optional thig in Next-Auth but It is a very important security object